# Data Generation Issue

Tags: c++, filtering, signal-processing

I'm having an issue with regards to writing data to a file in C++ due to an issue with a function I have developed. I load a `.dat` file from an external source into my C++ project. The while loop developed properly reads each data element line by line and passes it to a FIR filter function which takes three parameters, namely the filter length, filter coefficient `std::vector<float>` and a `float data`:

```
float f0 = 8000;
float fs = 32000;
int filt_length = 21;
float filtered,data;
fir_lowpass windowed_filter(f0,fs);

std::ifstream input;
std::ofstream output;
input.open("chirp.dat");
output.open("filter_test_sig.dat");

std::vector<float> blackman_choice,basic_lpf;

basic_lpf = windowed_filter.fir_sinc_filter_weights(filt_length);

blackman_choice = windowed_filter.blackman_window(filt_length, basic_lpf);

if (input.fail() && output.fail()) {
    std::cout << "Files not opened." << std::endl;
}
else{
    while (input >> data) {
        filtered = windowed_filter.generic_fir_filter(filt_length, blackman_choice, data);
        output << filtered << std::endl;
        std::cout << filtered << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I've confirmed that this loop indeed works as intended as I have a much less complex FIR filter header file. Here is the original function that works with the aforementioned code:

```
float lpf_filter(float input){

    forward_buffer[0] = input;
    float output;

    for (int i = 0; i<filter_length; i++) {
        output += B[i]*forward_buffer[i];
    }
    for (int i = filter_length-1; i>0; i--) {
        forward_buffer[i] = forward_buffer[i-1];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Note that the `array B` is predefined and is calculated inside *Matlab* and exported. In the next function, I have attempted to rewrite this function to take already calculated coefficients from another function. Here is the code and an example coefficient function under it (updated `float output = 0`):

```
float generic_fir_filter(const std::vector<float> &coefficients, float input){
    std::vector<float> buffer(coefficients.size(),0.0f);
    buffer[0] = input;
    float output = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<(int)coefficients.size(); i++) {
        output += coefficients[i]*buffer[i];
    }
    for (int i = (int)coefficients.size()-1; i>0; i--) {
        buffer[i] = buffer[i-1];
    }
    return output;
}
std::vector<float> fir_sinc_filter_weights(int filt_length){
    std::vector<float> w(filt_length);
    M = filt_length-1;

    for (int i = 0; i<filt_length; i++) {
        if (i == M/2) {
            w[i] = 2*fn;
        }
        else{
            w[i] = sin(2*M_PI*fn*(i-M/2))/(M_PI*(i-M/2));
        }
    }
    return w;
}
```

When I run this function inside my inner while loop in the `.cpp` file it only produces the same filtered value for each loop iteration whereas my original function did not. I also converted the loaded `.dat` file into a `std::vector<float>` and attempted to load samples one at a time but this did not work either. Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I have now moved my `std::vector<float> buffer` to the `private:` in an attempt to keep the previous remaining state inside the buffer. I have also added a small addition to the constructor to tell `std::vector<float> buffer` how many array elements it should have and to also initialise them all to zero. The problem now, is when I call for the buffer inside my `generic_fir_filter()` I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when I call for `buffer[0] = input;` inside the aforementioned function:

```
private:
   int M;
   float fn;
   std::vector<float> buffer;
public:
fir_lowpass(float f0,float fs,int weight_size){
    fn = f0/fs;
    std::vector<float> buffer(weight_size, 0.0f);
}
float generic_fir_filter(const std::vector<float> &coefficients, float input){
    //std::vector<float> buffer(coefficients.size(),0.0f);
    buffer[0] = input;
    float output = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<(int)coefficients.size(); i++) {
        output += coefficients[i]*buffer[i];
    }
    for (int i = (int)coefficients.size()-1; i>0; i--) {
        buffer[i] = buffer[i-1];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: In `generic_fir_filter()` output should be zero since you initialize all `buffer` elements to zero. But in `lpf_filter()`, you set only the first element of `forward_buffer` to zero. You did not show where the rest of it initialized.

Comment: What is the format of your `.dat` file? Is it binary? Are you checking the `input` stream for errors when you do `input >> data`?

Comment: Thanks for the swift response folk. I believe Shibli's recommendation was the issue but now I have another issue! I've ran my data through the filter but the output filtered values are absolutely tiny in comparison to what they should be. I double checked it by comparing to my Matlab version and the Matlab filter (which has nearly identical coefficients give or take rounding) and do not produce similar responses.

Comment: `buffer` should be a member (initialized with zeros unless you want to start your filtering with a given state) of your `fir_lowpass` class such that the state of the filter will persist over all the `generic_fir_filter` calls for each individual `input` sample.

Comment: Yeah this is the problem I have now. I'm unsure of how to maintain the state of `std::vector<float> buffer`. I added some break points and what you pointed out is happening. I essentially get almost consistently 0 values for my filtered response which is not what I wish to happen. Any suggestions with this would help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution to the issue of calling a `std:vector<float> buffer` and setting its array size to whatever I so require. The trick is to declare the buffer in the `private:` and then in the constructor setup and initialise the buffer via the following `:` operation beside the constructor name:

```
private:
int M;
float fn;
std::vector<float> buffer;
public:
fir_lowpass(float f0,float fs,int weight_size) : buffer(weight_size, 0.0f)
{
    fn = f0/fs;
    //std::vector<float> buffer2(weight_size, 0.0f);
}
```

Thanks for everyone's help!